# What happens to the code that is written after execution of history push in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

I generally use the Redirect component for routing. As we need to return the Redirect, it is pretty understandable. However, I am confused with using history objects. Actually in my code base after pushing some route into the history stack. There are so many actions and functions and dispatchers are being called.

When would the new routes component be mounted? If someone could not understand please see the below sample code.

```
const some_handler_func = () => {
  history.push('/component 2');
  setState('dummy');
  console.debug('checking') 
  //what happens to the above two lines.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `console.debug` will run as intended, but state change to your component might not work, because the component you try to change state on might be already unmounted.